# Twig: How to write a for loop with an integrated if condition based on a value

Tags: symfony, twig, shuffle, twig-extension

**the situation**

- I have a little symfony twig app, where I run a for loop to get all
  items shown.
- I want to let the user decide if his content is
  rendered in a specific order or randomly, for which I will use the
  twig extension function shuffle().
- If the user activates the checkbox shuffle in the backend, it will output yes for the variable activateShuffle.
- I want to activate the twig shuffle() extension, if the above
  mentions variable is yes

**the problem**

I have found a way to handle the requirement. But with the following way, I need to duplicate some code which seems very wrong to me.

Current Code:

```
{% if activateShuffle == 'yes' %}
    {% for item in images|shuffle() %}
        <div>
            <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
            <img src="{{ asset('images/')}}{{ item.imagename }}"/>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for item in images %}
        <div>
            <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
            <img src="{{ asset('images/')}}{{ item.imagename }}"/>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**the solution**

is there a way to define the if condition within the for loop? so that it checks if a variable has a specific value and adds the extension? So maybe something like this:

```
{% for item in images if activateShuffle == 'yes' add |shuffle() %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ asset('images/')}}{{ item.imagename }}"/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `images` variable depening on the value of `activateShuffle` before your loop like this:

```
{% if activateShuffle == 'yes' %}
    {% set images = images|shuffle() %}
{% endif %}

{% for item in images %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ asset('images/')}}{{ item.imagename }}"/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a macro:

```
{% macro render_images_conditional(images, doShuffle) %}
    {% if doShuffle %}
        {% set images = images|shuffle() %}
    {⅜ endif %}

    {% for item in images %}
        ...
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.render_images_conditional(images, shuffle) }}
```